# Pass Bash Script Argument to Python Email Script

Tags: python, bash, arguments

I have a Python notify script that takes an email address and a command on the terminal and sends email with standard error and standard output. In the bash script that calls this Python script, I run some other commands and make some log files...

I want to edit the Python script to allow another positional argument so I can attach a log file the bash script creates in previous steps. Here is the Python snippet that creates the attachment:

```
def make_attachment(filename, content):
    attachment = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    attachment.set_payload(content)
    Encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
    attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'+filename+'"')
    return attachment
```

and the snippet that attaches it:

```
msg.attach(make_attachment('result.log', filename))
```

for the `if __name__ == '__main__':` call, I'm using:

```
email_result(args.cmd.split(), args.email, args.log)
```

I should note that these scripts already work together when I don't use the `msg.attach(make_attachment('result.log', filename))` bit.

When I run the bash script, I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/user/scripts/notify.py", line 85, in <module>
        email_result(args.cmd.split(), args.email, args.log)
    File "/home/user/scripts/notify.py", line 66, in email_result
        msg.attach(make_attachment('result.log', filename))
    File "/home/user/scripts/notify.py", line 49, in make_attachment
        Encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/encoders.py", line 45, in encode_base64
        encdata = _bencode(orig)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/encoders.py", line 31, in _bencode
        hasnewline = (s[-1] == '\n')
TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I think I might have to use the bash trick `$@` but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Does the result.log file have content on every execution? Could this be because result.log is empty?

Comment: Good question... Couple things. I have this notify script running elsewhere and even when attachments are empty, they are delivered by email. They are just empty files. Plus, the file is created in the bash script, and it simply contains output from a command (which always returns something to the terminal if run). So yes, it should always contain something and should not be empty.

Comment: did you already debug by printing filename and content in the method ?